# Measure distance in km of polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, line, measurements

As much as I have looked numerous times for how to measure vector polyline in QGIS I can not find the way. This seems like an easy thing to do but the answer eludes me. Dah!

After I have traced out a route as a vector polyline on a map layer I sure would like to know how long in kilometres it is. The actual total line length with many points winding along a path.

And not by taking a Ruler tool to measure crudely the distance as you see on Google Maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new field with field calculator and this expression `$length/1000`.

This was the short answer. More details in what follows, as things are a bit more complicated.

---

**How to calculate length? Use QGIS expressions**

You can use QGIS expressions for that: `length($geometry)` or `$length`.  If unsure, use the second one (see below for more information).

To get km from m, divide by 1000: `length($geometry) / 1000` or `$length / 1000`.

**Where to apply the epxression? Add an attribute field or a label**

1. Create a new attribute field with [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=field%20calculator#using-the-field-calculator). Once calculated, it will be static and not change any more (you must explicitely update it).
2. Option to version 1: [create a virtual field](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=virtual%20field#creating-a-virtual-field). It updates dynamically when you change the line.
3. [Set a label](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html?highlight=label#setting-a-label) for visualization purpose. If you use an expression instead of a field as label source, it will update dynamically when you change the line. This case is shown in the screenshot below.

**What is the difference between the two expressions? Planimetric vs. ellipsoidal measurement**

[From documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=length#length):

> `length ($geometry)`: Calculations are always planimetric in the Spatial Reference System
> (SRS) of this geometry, and the units of the returned length will
> match the units for the SRS. This differs from the calculations
> performed by the `$length` function, which will perform ellipsoidal
> calculations based on the project’s ellipsoid and distance unit
> settings.

That means: if unsure about projection (see next point), use `$length` as it measures great circle distances (based on the ellipsoid defined in the CRS). `length($geometry)` however measures on the distorted map projection (flat canvas).

**Important remark: mind projection!**

Be aware of projection or [Coordinat Reference System](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/coordinate_reference_systems.html) (CRS, same as SRS): For your line-layer, [select a CRS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#coordinate-reference-system-selector) with units in meters (projected CRS) and one where [measurements make sense](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/coordinate_reference_systems.html#map-projections-with-equal-distance) (e.g. **not** `EPSG:3857`, this extremely distorts lengths and areas). Which CRS to use depends on the location and extent of your study area. See here a [reference list of CRS definitions](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/) or also have a look at https://epsg.io/.

See also [this answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396041/88814).

**Example**

Even with `EPSG:3857`, you can make more or less "accurate" measurements with using `$length`, **based on the ellipsoid used for the CRS**. So you should still consider to get a local CRS that is fit best to your study area - `WGS84` ellipsoid used for `EPSG:3857`is not the best bet. But if accuracy does not play a major role, you could still use it as follows:

An already classical example of measuring errors is the reach of missiles from North Korea. Years ago, the Economist published a [map with wrong measurements](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8026/examples-of-gis-projects-gone-wrong/8031#8031). As you can see in the linked post on the second map, the correct (geodesic/ great circle line) distance from North Korea to northern New Zealand is 10.000 km.

Now drawing a line with layer CRS `EPSG:3857` (an project CRS the same, but relevant for measuring is layer CRS) from North Korea to northern New Zealand. Aplly a label with the expression `$length/1000` to this line and you get the correct value, see screenshot. If I change the label expression to `length ($geometry)/1000`, it returns the (wrong) value 10.927 km).

[image]

Comment: So $length can give a great circle distance directly, but length() is Cartesian?

Comment: @wingnut: that's true. So if you measure in a CRS like `EPSG:3857`, than `$length` still returns a more or less correct value. `length($geometry)`, however, is meaningless. Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I got my measurements. Always thought this would be just an icon click or menu item to spit out the number. This is a bit more involved if I have to add a field to all my 150 separate trail layers.

Comment: You can use field calculator in batch mode to automatize this