# Adding up line length for lines that pass through polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, line, overlapping-features, length

I have three lines as per the below picture. The layer is called *'line'*. A is 60m, B is 30m and C is 90m. I have a polygon layer consisting of 1 square. The layer is called *'polygon'*.

I want to make a calculated field called `"ttl_length"` in the polygon layer which is the total length of all lines that pass through the polygon. In other words, the total should be 180m.

[image]

I am currently using the below-calculated field:

```
aggregate(layer:='line',
      aggregate:='sum',
      expression:= "line_length" ,
      filter:=intersects(geometry(@parent), $geometry) 
      )
```

The above will only give me the sum of the length of lines actually inside the square. I need the length of all the lines (eg. 180m). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
coalesce(
 aggregate(layer:='line99',
 aggregate:='sum',
 expression:=length($geometry),
 filter:=intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent))),
0)
```

Aggregate:
"Returns an aggregate value calculated using features from another layer."

The aggregate to calculate is sum, and the values to sum are the lengths of the lines intersecting `@parent` feature which is each polygon.

For the polygons that doesnt intersect any line the value will be `NULL` and coalesce is returning 0 for these features.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to achieve that is to use [`overlay_intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects) to create an array of the lengths of all intersecting lines, then calculate the sum with [`array_sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-sum):

```
array_sum (overlay_intersects ('line', length($geometry)))
```

To calculate [ellipsoidal length](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397278/88814), you could also use `$length` instead of `length($geometry)`.